# How to jump to anchor with invalid Django form?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

When my Django form fails to validate it automatically goes back to the page where the form failed but I'd like it to go to an html anchor on the page. Here's the code I have:

```
def detail(request, post_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    # get all the comments for the post
    comments = p.comment_set.all().order_by('pub_date')
    # to add a comment to the post
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            c = Comment()
            c.body = request.POST['body']
            c.post = p
            c.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('journal.views.detail', kwargs={'post_id': post_id}) + "#comment-" + str(c.id))
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'posts/detail.html', {'post': p, 'comments': comments, 'form': form})
```

The form is a comment form at the bottom of a blog post. When the form is invalid I'd like it to jump to the comment form's html anchor at the bottom of the page. Right now it goes to the top of the page and you have to scroll down to notice that there's an error.

I tried a couple things that didn't work. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

I think that is fair enough:

```
  <script>
    function goToId() {
      if (!window.location.hash) window.location = window.location + '#your-id';
    }
    {% if form.is_bound %}
      $(window).on("load", goToId);
    {% endif %}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to pass an extra key-value pair in the dict to contain the anchor name, and use JavaScript in the template to jump to it if needed.

Python side:

```
// ...
return render(request,
              'post/detail.html',
              {
                  // ...
                  'anchor': 'comment'
              })
```

The template:

```
function goToOnLoadAnchor()
{
    window.location.hash('{{ anchor }}');   // Or something with the same effect
}

{% ... %}
<body onload="goToOnLoadAnchor">
{% ... %}
```

You can also take advantage of custom template tags to add more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

### CBV & jQuery

**FormView**

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, anchor='my-form'))
```

**template**

```
<form ... id='my-form'> ... </form>
<script>
    $(function () {
        {% if anchor %}
            $(document.body).animate({
                'scrollTop':   $('#{{ anchor }}').offset().top
            }, 2000);
        {% endif %}
    });
</script>
```

Uses jQuery for scrolling (instead of jumping).

Answer (score 0):

With Vanilla JavaScript:

```
{% if form.is_bound %}
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById("your_id").scrollIntoView();
  });
</script>
{% endif %}
```

It works well with the `addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")` listener. Otherwise it can give some weird results.